# UIScrollView with active and inactive areas

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll

I have a `UIScrollView` that takes up my whole screen with a vertical toolbar on one side, and I need to constrain the scrolling behavior such that the user can only scroll by dragging the toolbar.  If they try to drag from anywhere else on the screen no scrolling should take place.

I've tried overriding `touchesBegan`, `touchesShouldCancelInContentView`, and `touchesShouldBegin` so that if the touch doesn't originate in the toolbar I call `setScrollEnabled:NO` and if it does I call `setScrollEnabled:YES`, but it seems like once scrolling is disabled the methods no longer fire and I'm deadlocked.  Also tried setting up the toolbar as a button and enabling scrolling on `touchDown` and disabling on `touchUpInside` and `touchUpOutside`.  This also doesn't work.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a second scrollview to control the main scroll view. I added a gradient to be able to see the scrolling.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation ScrollViewController {
    UIScrollView *mainScrollView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect mainScrollViewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width - 100, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    mainScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:mainScrollViewRect];
    mainScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 100, 1000);
    [self.view addSubview:mainScrollView];

    CAGradientLayer* gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, mainScrollView.contentSize.width, mainScrollView.contentSize.height);
    gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [mainScrollView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];

    CGRect toolbarRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 100, 0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    UIScrollView *toolbarScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:toolbarRect];
    toolbarScrollView.delegate = self;
    toolbarScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, 1000);
    toolbarScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbarScrollView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    mainScrollView.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

@end
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in my initial description.  The toolbar is not a scrollview; it's just an anchor point that the user can click on and then drag across the screen like opening a curtain by dragging it from the end.  Make sense?

Comment: Not really, do you have an image of what you're trying to do? Do you mean a vertical slider by saying toolbar like a curtain?

Comment: let me start over.  the app launches in landscape mode with a scrollview filling the whole screen and a vertical "bar" along the left edge.  the content area of the scrollview is twice as wide as the screen, but the user should only be able to scroll by dragging the bar from the left side to the right side (and back again).  swipe gestures anywhere else should be ignored.  I originally called it a "toolbar" because it's going to have buttons on it related to other functionality.